# The adaptor not showing the Array list items in List view but show the string in Toast msg which used for test

Tags: java, android, api, listview, android-volley

I write this code to fetch data from URL and get the title from each JSON object and show this in the list view. The problem is data is stored successfully in productlist variable, which I check it by Log.d and Toast massage method. but it not show in listview.

```
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject productfromjson = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        productList.add(productfromjson.getString("title"));
                    }
                    Log.d("products", String.valueOf(productList));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(productList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
        }
```

the following is the adaptor code
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productList);
myproducts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: could you post adapter code, and create adapter part?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productList);
        myproducts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: if i do-------  productList.add("hello world")    ----- then hello world show in list view but if i add the value through response as shown above, it get add in the productList which is ArrayList variavle but not shown in listview

Comment: myproducts is my list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to notify `adapter` about `dataset` changes using `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRangeInserted()` like below

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
     try {
         for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
             JSONObject productfromjson = response.getJSONObject(i);
             productList.add(productfromjson.getString("title"));
          }
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          Log.d("products", String.valueOf(productList));
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(productList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: ok but can you please tell me how to do it in adaptor this is my adaptor code

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productList);
        myproducts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: I have added `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in `onResponse`, replace your `onResponse` method with above `onResponse`

Comment: The answer of @rajan.kali will be helpful for you. My thought is same as him. I upvote his answer.

Comment: hey problem solved thanks brother Thanks a Lot

Comment: arrayAdapter.add(productfromjson.getString("title"));
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

brother you don't have used notifyDataSetChanged();
Here is how you will do it.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productList); 
 myproducts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
 try {
     for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
         JSONObject productfromjson = response.getJSONObject(i);
         productList.add(productfromjson.getString("title"));
      }
      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationcontext, String.valueOf(productList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the adapter know that the data in the list has changed by adding this line into your code:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So your code should look like this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
     try {
         for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
             JSONObject productfromjson = response.getJSONObject(i);
             productList.add(productfromjson.getString("title"));
          }
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          Log.d("products", String.valueOf(productList));
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(productList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```